# Symmetry property for binominal coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I am looking at the slides from this [here](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse547/ch5p14.pdf).
On slide 5 they have the following

$$
(-1)^{m+l} \sum_{k \leq l}\left(\begin{array}{c}{l-k} \\ {m}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}{s} \\ {k-n}\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k-m+l}
$$

They then state the following on slide 6,

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { Now since } k \leq l, l, m, n \in \mathbf{Z} ; \text { and } l, m, n \geq 0 \text { we }} \\ {\text { can use our symmetry property on the left hand }} \\ {\text { side to obtain: }} \\ {(-1)^{l+m} \sum_{k \leq l} \left(\begin{array}{c}{l-k} \\ {l-k-m}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}{s} \\ {k-n}\end{array}\right)(-1)^{l-k-m}}\end{array}
$$

My question is then, why are they rewriting the very last exponent from $k-m+l$ to $l-k-m$?.  Maybe i am missing something fundamental butthis doesn't seem clear to me given their definition of the symmetry property in the beginning of the slides.

Comment: $k-m+l$ and $l-k-m$ have the same parity, since they differ by $2m$.

Comment: @rogerl ah yes of course. So this is actually unrelated to the symmetry property, and just for convenience?

Comment: I think that "symmetry property" perhaps means $\binom{l-k}{m} = \binom{l-k}{l-k-m}$

Comment: @rogerl Don't they differ by $2k$?

Comment: $\binom{l-k}{m}=\frac{(l-k)!}{m!(l-k-m)!}=\binom{l-k}{l-k-m}$, since $m+(l-k-m)=l-k$.

Comment: @user yes, sorry. Same result, though.